# Как правильно подставить переменные в запрос mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Пытаюсь обновить запись в  таблице  contract.

```
<?php
    echo "Сообщение отправлено!";

    // Получаем данные от js
    $contract_id = $_POST["contract_id"];
    $contract_name = $_POST["contract_name"];
    $contract_html = $_POST["contract_html"];
    $contract_date = $_POST["contract_date"];

    // Параметры подключения
    $host = "localhost";
    $database = "base";
    $user = "user";
    $password = "pass";

    // Создаем подключение
    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);
    if (!$link) {
        echo "Ошибка" . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Код ошибки errno: " . mysqli_connect_errno() . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Текст ошибки: " . mysqli_connect_error() . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }

    echo "Соединение установлено!" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Информация о сервере: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link) . PHP_EOL;

    // Выполняем операции с БД
    $query = 'UPDATE contract SET (contract_name = $contract_name, contract_html = $contract_html, contract_date = $contract_date, WHERE contract_id = $contract_id';

    if(mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        echo "Запись добавлена!";
    } else {
        echo "Запись НЕ добавлена!";
    }

    // Закрываем подключение
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

В результате получаю "Запись НЕ добавлена".

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

**Во-первых** вам надо прочитать отличие одинарных и двойных кавычек в PHP

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

**Во-вторых**, даже при этом знании надо будет понимать, что внутри строки, надо будет заносить ещё строки, поэтому надо будет писать доп. кавычки. В принципе можно об этом прочитать в том же разделе и в разделе обработки строк https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

**В-третьих**, даже в этом случае запрос будет неверным, т.к. будет подвержен [SQL инъекциям](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/security.database.sql-injection.php). И самый верный способ - использовать [подготовленные запросы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.prepared-statements.php) , [ещё ссылка на подготавливаемые запросы](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). В таком случае и волноваться о проблеме правильной подстановки переменных не придётся

Подгтовленные запросы поддерживают такие драйверы как *mysqli* (не путать с СУБД mysql)  и *PDO* (наиболее популярный)